# Delete Items After List View Threshold Breached

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-view-threshold, edit-update-delete

So I was doing a migration the other day, and due to poor planning on my part a situation has now arisen where certain subfolders (each subfolder relates to a single property) now contain over 5000 items. I need to delete all this migrated data (by filtering on the booked property field and the creation date) but I can't even SEE it thanks to SharePoint Online's immutable list view threshold (thanks again, Microsoft).

How can I delete the items that match the conditions specified now I can't even see them in the browser? I suspect possibly via CAML or somesuch but I'm unsure how to go about it and I really need a quick answer as it's part of a project that should've been finished by now, but isn't due to a) technical issues like this and b) client changing their mind every day about one thing or the other.

Comment: Do you have access to powershell?

Comment: Yes I have full tenant admin access.

Comment: Take a look at this:  https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/16487710-prioritize-large-list-management-in-sharepoint-onl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to modify the default view in the SharePoint list by SharePoint list ID.

For example you could set the list items to only appear when list ID is greater than 0 and equal to or less than 500. This would display the first 500 items. You can then delete these and then continue this process until the items are all removed.

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure if that will work as the IDs aren't necessarily sequential, but I'll try it, cheers.

Comment: No Problem, it is worth a shot. Can always use datasheet view to bulk delete the items if you manage to create a view by ID as well.